# How can i get this jquery sliding effect with AJAX?

Tags: ajax, jquery

how can i get this jquery sliding effect with AJAX..

http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_44012/index.html

i search in google but always appear the sliding effect passing thorugh all the divs previous from the destination one.

Anyone knows how to slideOut the actual and go directly thorugh the required one?

i know is using AJAX but i cant apply it yet.

THanks!

Comment: This is probably a better fit for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. *However*, I would strongly suggest that you construct a more reasonable question than basically asking "how do I get first on google?", and ensure that your question hasn't already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an entire industry sub-sector dedicated to SEM/SEO. There is no single technique that will work like magic.

Here is Google's starter guide on the topic:

http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf